# Intellisense for javascript files in VS Code from type definitions which have import

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

guys.

I'm trying to declare custom types in d.ts files and use it in jsdoc annotations in javascript files to have intellisense in VS Code.

Example is the following:

File types.d.ts

```
import { Request } from "express";

declare interface IRouter {
    request: Request,
    someProp: string

    ....
}
```

And when I'm trying to use it in @type, intellisense doesn't work.

E.g.,
someFile.js

```
/// <reference path="types.d.ts"/>
/**
 * @type {IRouter}
 */
 let customRouter;
```

So, when I use variable "customRouter", VSCode doesn't provide intellisense about possible properties. But if I will remove import from d.ts file - then all works ok.

What can be wrong in such case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: type declaration files are not transpiled, so you can't use import. Just use the type declaration files for all the libraries that you use - in this case `Express` ?. You also don't need the reference path. And finally, if you just say `let customRouter`, then typescript can't infer the type. You have to say `let customRouter:IRouter`

Answer (score 3):

Adding the `import` makes your `d.ts` file into a module you won't be able to pick up ambient types like `IRounter` anymore.

To fix this, either:

1. Add an import in your js files:

   ```
   import { IRouter } from "./types";

   /**
    * @type {IRouter}
    */
   let customRouter;
   ```
2. Or use declare global in your `d.ts`:

   ```
   import { Request } from "express";

   declare global {
       export interface IRouter {
           request: Request,
           someProp: string;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works also without import statement in JS file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd say that's how TypeScript works, just to clear it up.
IF there are not definition files beside `.js` dist files OR `@types/<library-name>` package installed, TypeScript just won't know-how.

That said, I am using IntelliJ Ultimate and that Typing works out of the box.
I guess they do some additional work to have it work.

#### As for VCode...

You'll see that VSCode doesn't even want to autocomplete the filename.

The trick to working this around was to ruse TypeScript with [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) `/// <reference`

```js
/// <reference path="node_modules/bpmn-js/lib/Modeler.js"/>
import Modeler from 'bpmn-js/lib/Modeler';

new Modeler()
```

[image]

**Now, this' more of a feature to suggest to VSCode team rather than a true limitation.**